# how to use CoreTelephony framework

Tags: objective-c, core-telephony

can any one help me in understanding CoreTelephony framework by telling among any one given below

- any simple apps example that is using core-telephony framework
- i am able to  add core-telephony framework but not able to import any header file of it

although they exist in frameworks that  i have added

any help will be appreciable as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CoreTelephony files imported using <> not ""
For example:

```
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
```